# Returning 500 internal error when CompleteableFuture throws exception

Tags: java, dropwizard

I have a rest controller that has an endpoint:

```
@GET
@Path("/reindex-record")
public String reindexRecord(@QueryParam("id") String id) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(
            () -> runWithException(Reindexer::reindexAll));
    } else {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> runWithException(
            () -> Reindexer.reindexOne(id)));
    }

    // return "ok" or throw WebApplciationException from runWithException method below
}
```

and here is my wrapper method - both methods - reindexAll and reindexOne throw checked exceptions so decided to use wrapper method and interface:

```
public interface RunnableWithException {
    void run() throws Exception; 
}

private void runWithException(RunnableWithException task) {
    try {
        task.run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error occured during async task execution", e);
        throw new WebApplicationException(
            Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .entity("Internal error occurred").build());
    }
}
```

The problem is that I want to run this task asnychronously using CompleteableFuture and give a response only after given task is done or if there was an error throw WebApplicationException with INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR status.

How would you implement that in my use-case with if/else?

EDIT:
As of now I have this method:

```
@GET
@Path("/reindex-record")
public String reindexRecord(@QueryParam("id") String id) throws ExecutionException,
    InterruptedException {
    CompletableFuture<Void> task;
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
        task = CompletableFuture.runAsync(
            () -> runWithException(Reindexer::reindexAll));
    } else {
        task = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> runWithException(
            () -> Reindexer.reindexOne(id)));
    }
    return task.thenApply(x -> "ok")
        .exceptionally(throwable -> {
            log.error("Error occured during async task execution", throwable);
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                                                  .entity("Internal error occurred. Try again later")
                                                  .build());

        }).get();

}
```

But if error is thrown by any of Reindexer methods I'm still getting status 500 with data:

```
{
"code": 500,
"message": "There was an error processing your request. It has been logged (ID 03f09a62b62b1649)."
```

}

Instead of 503 defined in my `exceptionally` block.
Using dropwizard with JAX-RS if that matters.

Comment: You can't. Either you wait/block. Or the client needs to send another request, to check if it has failed.

Comment: I'm ok with blocking - those methods just send some stuff to the Rabbit queue so it's very fast operation but can throw some unexpected errors.

Comment: This may be helpful http://humansreadcode.com/spring-boot-completablefuture/

Answer (score 1):

You can change the body of your method to this:

```
@GET
@Path("/reindex-record")
public String reindexRecord(@QueryParam("id") String id) {
    final CompletableFuture<Void> future;
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
        future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(
            () -> runWithException(Reindexer::reindexAll));
    } else {
        future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(
            () -> runWithException(() -> Reindexer.reindexOne(id)));
    }

    // this will block
    future.get();

    return "ok";
}
```

By storing the future, you can then call the `get()` method on it, which will block until the future is finished.

From the javadoc of `CompletableFuture.get()`:

> Waits if necessary for this future to complete, and then returns its result.

Comment: It's not doing what I want actually. If exception is thrown by reindexAll then the user doesn't get INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROE

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `exceptionally()` for something it wasn't intended. `CompletableFuture`is intented to be used in a chain of `CompletableFuture`s where the output of one feeds into the next one. What happens if one of the `CompletableFuture`s throws an exception? You can use `exceptionally` to catch that and return a new fallback `ComletableFuture` for the next step of the chain to use instead.

You're not doing that, you just throw an `WebApplicationException`. The CompleteableFuture views that as a failure in the chain and wraps your `WebApplicationException` inside an `ExecutionException`. Dropwizard only sees the ExecutionException (it doesn't inspect any wrapped ones) and throws the generic 500 response.

The answer is just do the `future.get();` in @Lino's answer, but wrapped in a try...catch block for ExecutionException, and then throw WebApplicationException from the catch.

```
try {
    // this will block
    future.get();
} catch (ExecutioException) {
    throw new WebApplicationException(
        Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .entity("Internal error occurred").build());
}

return "ok";
```

You might be able to shorten the whole `throw new WebApplicationException(...` to simple `throw new InternalServerErrorException()`